# Transactional service causing ErrorController to Render instead of desired view

Tags: grails, error-handling

I've inherited a grails project in which an Error Controller is used.

Within the `URLMappings` there is the following entry:

```
"500"(controller: 'error', action:'error')
```

The specific errorController renders a specific view:

```
 render view:'/error/prodError'
```

What I don't understand is how to bypass error controller for 500 errors and send to view `/play/play` **but without removing the old one for other situations**.

Even though I catch exceptions from the playService, I still get `/error/prodError` instead of `/play/play`.

I've debugged the code and seen that the `render` method is called twice. It is called once to go to `/play/play` but another time for `/error/prodError` when an exception is thrown in the service and the transaction is rolled back.

See playController excerpt below:

**PlayController**

```
try{
playService.play(parame:params} //Runtime exception thrown from playService. 
//play is transactional
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
    //Why isn't /play/play rendered? 
//How do I pass errors to playservice for alert rendering?
    render view: '/play/play',
                            model: [
                                domain: domain,
                                customer: customer,
                                game: game]
                        return
            }
```

**Update**

Specifically, the errorController is entered because of an `UnexpectedRollbackException` that is the result of the rollback.

SO: How would someone go about not entering the `ErrorController` for a specific type of `Exception` that results from a specific `Controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to handle the error within a controller, you could render your (or any other) view with the following url mapping:

```
"500"(view:'/play/play')
```

If you need to handle individual exception you do it like this:

```
static mappings = {
    .
    .
    .
    "500"(controller: "error", action: "unexpectedRollback", exception: UnexpectedRollbackException)
    "500"(controller: "errors", action: "nullPointer", exception: NullPointerException)
    .
    .
    "500"(controller: 'error', action:'error')
}
```

As mentioned in [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/single.html#mappingToResponseCodes) you should avoid throwning exceptions from your error controller due to `StackOverflowExceptions`. I think it's not possible to divide between two exceptions of the same type but thrown from diffent controller.

If you handle the exception within your error controller you could try to set the response code directly. So - the url mapping may not handle your already handled exception.

Comment: Where would I put that? Is that globally applicable for all errors? I've updated my answer to include more information.

Comment: This is interesting. What is more than one place throw `UnexpectedRollbackException1 ? Then do I need to check within the `ErrorController` the `request` in order to find who threw it? If for example I want a different action for one specific situation.

Comment: Sounds promising! You should try it. :-)